# Django multiple model query latest 3 in total

Tags: django, django-models

I have 5 different models....similar structure but seperated due to lots of record so easier management and scalability.

I'm not sure if this is possible with django, but i have a div on the website which is called latest....i want to grab the latest 3 records and show it in this div....however having 5 different models its difficult....each have a timestamp field. Is it possible to query something like show latest 3 records in total, but check 5 of these models and display?

Usually if it was in one model I could have just easily said show latest x....but separated models makes its complicated. So i don't want to grab latest 3 records from each model....rather 3 in total but just consider from 5 different models and show latest 3 (either through filtering of id of timestamp field)

Please kindly let me know if there is a solution.

Comment: can you show 5 models?

Answer (score 0):

There is two different solution.

At first you can merge models and make a general model with common columns and each of 5 models connect to general model with ForeignKey. So you can make query on general model and access specific columns with related objects.

Second way is using[django contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes)